# Phonegap App got black screen on Android version 4.3 or lower

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

My App (Click Sick) get's a black screen on Android devices with 4.3 or lower.
I made my app with Phonegapp and it's only working on Android devices with 4.4 or higher.

Here is the config.xml of my project:

http://pastebin.com/MDDDm4PQ

I am using document.ready function instead of device ready in my game.js
Could this be the problem?

Comment: Have you plugged in a device into your dev machine and run the app? If not, try that and look at log cat and see what it says? I am curious and you should be to. ;)

Comment: Check the manifest file for apk version